# PhD without any help from advisor

Tags: phd, advisor

I have problems with my PhD advisor.
I do not want to talk about these problems, it will not be of any use anyway. We had mediation meeting between us.
In short, my advisor did not help me, support me or guide to me at all during my doctorate. He taught me how to use the devices, then I did everything myself.

I have no relationship with him.
I started my doctorate about 6 months before the pandemic. I don't have any networking.
I tried to change my advisor, but

1- There is no person working in this field in the research center or I do not know. But the responsible person in charge of the students said that this could happen. I don't need expert advisor in this field I am about to finish my studies. I need someone who can give me advise, direction etc.

2-I don't want to look like a rebel against my other advisor (professor) from the university.
Also, people generally believe what my advisor (in research center) says, not me and his image is very good.

He will change his university in few months (in the same city) and the last thing he wrote to me was; "I can further support you by proof reading your manuscripts and thesis and discussing its contents but I cannot further supervise".

I want to have a post doc. I am not unsuccessful. I wrote two papers myself.

Problem I am completely alone in my work and academic career.

Another problem is that he did everything for his other student, let me just give you an example, he said to me that he is not responsible from my career, but I know that he's looking for a job for his other student.

What should I do in this situation? I really need any advise or need every suggestion. I don't know how should I do. I do not want to work with him because I know that he will not support me in the future. I feel I did not learn anything.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where are you in the program? Close to the start or close to the end? Finished? It is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry, close to end. I completed my experiments. I am working on papers and then thesis.

Comment: Some parts of your description appear similar to my experience as a PhD student. I also didn't have "any networking" and minimal support from my adviser. However, they were a favorable examiner and gave me good referrals, which enabled my successful career. That should be your goals: finish the PhD and get good LORs.

Comment: I'm not clear on what problem you are trying to solve. You say the problem is that you are alone, but you also say that you've had a number of successes. Are you able to stay at the university after your supervisor leaves? Do you need a different supervisor for PhD, or are you confident about graduating and just worried about finding a next position? Are you worried about a LOR?

Answer (score 2):

The only quick answer we can give you I suspect is that you have to **survive on your own now**. Your relations with your advisor sound like severely damaged, and he does not want to help you any more beyond the minimum expected from him at this point, for some reason we don't know (perhaps he got disappointed with something you did, or he doesn't believe in you any more, he lost interest, he doesn't have time, he lost the plot, he is a "bad" person? etc.).

Finish the thesis, and be proactive in forming new scientific relations, and search actively a postdoc position on your own. Many people do it alone any way. The most important thing is to be professional. You don't "want" to work with him? Perhaps, but probably you need to work with him a bit now to finish the thesis.

Comment: Very practical advice.